# Is there always a comma before and after a year in a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas

What is the correct punctuation of comma usage for the following sentence?

> I began my general studies in June 2010 at OTC in Springfield, Missouri.

Comment: It's fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

A comma is not needed when only month and year are given. If the date is added, then a comma should separate the year from whatever follows in the sentence (June 2, 2010, was the best day in Fred's life.) If the more British order for the date is given, no commas are required. (The contract was signed on 2 June 2010 at the attorney's office.)

Chicago Manual of Style, 16th Edition, p. 322.